# How do you send SVN commit emails from a hosted repository?

Tags: svn, teamcity

Until recently my team has worked with self-hosted SVN and used SubversionNotify to send out well-formatted commit notification emails.

We are migrating to a hosted SVN repository which means we no longer have direct access to the server on which SVN runs. As a result we can't install SubversionNotify. I've considered trying to invoke SubversionNotify remotely, but it relies on the svnlook command which only works when executed on the host server. The host does not provide any way to use SVN hooks.

We have TeamCity and are able to fire tasks when something has changed in the repo - is there any way to create the emails using this technique?

Answer (score 1):

You should ask your SVN hoster this question. The answer strictly depends on the options the hoster offers.

Comment: I've updated the question as it wasn't clear sorry. Our host does not allow us to use server-side SVN hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Your hoster will do it or offer in app ways to install post commit hooks.

Comment: Unfortunately they don't. Have updated question to reflect this.

Comment: For what it's worth Assembla let's you install your own hooks across various Svn stages. We also have well formatted emails for commits out of box.

Comment: @JacekMaterna FYI: the link to GitHub profile on your StackOverflow profile gives 404. ;)

Comment: @JacekMaterna thanks, we've actually decided to close the account and switch to GitHub now.